# Filter multiple signs with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to filter out * / % using a regex. The following ones are the ones I have tried this far:

```
String reg = "[\\*]||[/]||[%]";
String reg2 = "[*]||[/]||[%]";
String reg3 = "*/%";
```

All of the above gives this same Exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0 *
```

However, I do have another one which sorts out a bit more:

```
String reg4 = "[0-9\\*+\\-/%]";
```

That one works perfectly fine.

I also tried only sorting out the signs individually, the only one I struggle with is " * ". What I have tried with only that one is:

```
String reg1 = "*";
String reg2 = "\\*";
String reg3 = "[\\*]";
```

Both give the same exception I mentioned earlier.

---

Relevant code:

```
/*
* calc1 is an ArrayList<String>
*/
public void solve() {
    while(calc1.size() > 1) {
        for(int i = 0; i < calc1.size(); i++) {
            if(calc1.get(i).matches("regex")) calculate(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(calc1.toString());
}
```

---

EDIT

Suggestions tried:

```
String reg = "[*/%]";
String reg2 = "[\\*/%]";
```

Comment: Why not put all into a character class: `[*/%]`? See [demo](http://ideone.com/X75vjQ)

Comment: Ah, I think you concatenate the subpatterns with `|`, right? **Please show all the relevant code.**

Comment: I got the same Exception unfortunatly

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I know I don't have to, but I figured I could try that as well

Comment: Do you know that `matches` requires a full string match? Use Matcher#find().

Comment: I guess you want to replace the `if(calc1.get(i).matches("regex")) calculate(i);` with `if(calc1.get(i).matches("(?s).*" + regex + ".*")) calculate(i);`  where `regex` is the variable containing `[*/%]` or whatever you have. You still have not shown the full *relevant* code.

Comment: I don't have any more code building upon what I just showed. All I do in calculate is to print out the index and what symbols comes with it. Your previous suggestion seems to work.

Comment: In a nutshell what I am trying to do here, is to see I can make a filter where only the Strings containing only (and nothing else) the symbols defined in the regex gets through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `String#matches` requires a full string match. Either use a `Matcher#find()` (it will require more code), or use

```
if(calc1.get(i).matches("(?s).*" + regex + ".*")) calculate(i);
```

where `regex` is the variable containing `[*/%]` or whatever regex you have.

The `(?s)` will make sure the `.` will also match a newline, and thus will ensure a full string (containing the characters you defined in the character class(es)) match.

If you want to only process strings that *equal* a pattern, you do not need the `.*` bits, but you need to apply a quantifier (if there can be more than one):

```
if(calc1.get(i).matches(regex + "+")) calculate(i);
```

This final `+` will match one or more occurrences of the symbols in the character classes.